# Timing CSS animation events

Tags: css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to time the execution of events. In this case, the div should slide down from the top, and then grow by 10%. I tried stacking the animations, as a best guess, but this doesn't work.

```css
@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
    
#theDiv {
  animation-name: slideDown grow;
  animation-duration: 3s 3s;  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease ease;
  transition-delay: 0s 3s;
  
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">HELLO, WORLD!</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `transform` atttibute with multiple animation. If you call both of animation "slideDown" and "grow", it only applying "grow" animation.

So if you want animate "grow" after "slideDown", merge both anmiation.

```css
@keyframes stacked-anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

#theDiv {
  animation-name: stacked-anim;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">HELLO, WORLD!</div>
```

If you animate different attributes, you can set multiple animation with comma.

```css
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: crimson;
  }
}

#theDiv {
  animation-name: changeColor, grow;
  animation-duration: 3s, 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease, ease;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv">HELLO, WORLD!</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-composition